# user name is string empty when migrating .net1.1 webapp to .net4

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-7, iis-7.5

i create a new hello world web app on windows7+iis7.5+windows authentication+asp.net4.
with the configuration above i was successed to get the user name with this line of code:

```
Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.
```

but when i try the same line of code on my web app which was migrate from asp.net1.1 but use the same configuration above, i get an empty string, why?

Answer (score 0):

You probably get an empty string **because you try to ask this from a non secure page**, and at the same time you have set on web.config the `requireSSL="true"`

If you have set the requireSSL="true" , then the cookie to check and read the user is get it only from https pages.

Also check that you have set the `domain="yourdomain.com"`

this settings are on web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".youkeyname" path="/" requireSSL="true" domain="yourDomain.com" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: i didn't find "requireSSL" in my web app project.

Comment: @yaron on the web.config, on authentication, maybe is true by default, try to make it false if you like to see if this is it.

Comment: there is no requireSSL in the web.config. can you write the lines that i need to add to my web.config. thanks.

Comment: sory for the confusing, but it's an intranet app which use windows authentication and not forms authentication.

Comment: i start to focus more on the problem and here it is, i successed to get the user name from a page in my app BUT NOT FROM INSIDE MY CUSTOM HTTP MODULE , which is a my custom windows authentication module, there i am handling the authentication request event and there i can't get the user name. maybe i didn't implemented well a custom windows authentication modue.

Comment: i switch to asp.net v4.0 classic application pool, and this solved the problem.

Comment: i stay with integrated application pool mode, but move the interception to PostAuthenticationRequest (before it was in the AuthenticationRequest event handler), and now it's work.